# PayPal Webhooks not working on Recurring payments

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk, paypal-subscriptions, paypal-webhooks

I have implemented recurring payments using PayPal Rest API. I have subscribed to some events of webhooks. When the subscription is created, I got a notification from paypal. But when the recurring payment created I have not get any notification, even on the events console of developer account.

Comment: Did you find a way to solve this?

Comment: Yes I have found a way for this. I have used "Transactions" of PayPal REST APIs. On each recurring payment time, I get all the transactions against the transaction id and on the basis of agreement id, update the status of recurring payment in my system.

Comment: Just commenting, I gave paypal a chance but I found out that there are many issues with the webhooks. Sometimes they send incomplete data and you have to jump around and see what they didn't send. If I were you, I would stay away from paypal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a solution to get the list of transactions from transaction API and on the basis of agreement id verify the transaction you want.